# OpenGL glut glTranslate glRotate glScale matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glut, translate-animation

i'm looking for an explanation (or an image) of the matrix and how it changes when putting translate, rotate and scale on it... (one cell with sin(angle), and another cell with x coord of translate)

Answer (score 3):

For now, ignore translation, it's a slightly trickier concept than rotation and scale.

The way to think about this is that each matrix defines a change in the basis vectors. Given a standard co-ordinate system, your basis vectors are `(1,0,0)`, `(0,1,0)` and `(0,0,1)`. For now, I'm just going to assume a 2D system, as the concepts carry through, but it's less work.

I'm also assuming column-major. I can't remember if OpenGL actually uses this though, so check this first, and optionally transpose the matrices if needed.

The basis vectors, as defined before, can be put in matrix form. This simply puts each vector as a column in the matrix. Therefore, to transform from the basis vectors to the basis vectors (i.e. no change), we would use the following matrix. This is also called the "identity matrix", since it doesn't do anything to its input (similar to how *1 is the identity of multiplication).

```
2D         3D
(1 0)      (1 0 0)
(0 1)      (0 1 0)
           (0 0 1)
```

I've included the 3D version for completeness sake, but that's as far as I'll be taking 3D.

A scale matrix can be seen as "stretching" the axes. If the axes are twice as large, the intervals on them will be twice as far apart, thus, the contents will be larger. Take this as an example

```
(2 0)
(0 2)
```

This will change the basis vectors from `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)` to `(2, 0)` and `(0, 2)`, thus making the whole shape represented twice as large. Diagrammatically, see below.

```
 Before                   After
6|                        3|
5|                         |
4|                        2|-------|
3|                         |       |
2|--|                     1|       |
1|__|___________           |_______|______
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7           0   1    2    3
```

The same then happens for rotation, although instead, we sue different values, the values for a rotation matrix are as follows:

```
(cos(x)   -sin(x))
(sin(x)    cos(x))
```

This will effectively rotate each axis around the angle `x`. To really make sense of this, brush up on your trig and assume each column is a new basis vector ;).

Now, translation is a little trickier. For this, we add an extra column at the end of the matrix, which for all other operations just has a `1` on the last row (i.e. it is an identity, of forms). For translation, we fill this in as follows:

```
(1 0 x)
(0 1 y)
(0 0 1)
```

This is 3D in a form, but not in the form you will be used to. You can model this as moving the Z basis co-ordinate (and remember, we're working in 2D here!), assuming your model exists at `Z=1`. This effectively skews the shape, but again, as we're working in 2D, it is flattened so we don't percieve the third dimension. If we were working in 3D here, this would actually be the fourth dimension, as can be seen here:

```
(1 0 0 x)
(0 1 0 y)
(0 0 1 z)
(0 0 0 1)
```

Again, the "fourth dimension" isn't seen, but we instead move along it and flatten. It's easier to get your head around it in 2D space first, then try and extrapolate. In 3D space, this fourth dimension vector is called `w`, so your models implicitly lie at `w=1`.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: As an aside, this page is what helped me to understand translation matrices. It has some decent diagrams, so hopefully it will be more helpful:
http://www.blancmange.info/notes/maths/vectors/homo/

Comment: +1 for the effort... I want ASCII art for rotation though! :)